# VS Code: Can I show multiple repositories in SCM at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

Before VS Code January 2020 update, I could see multiple repos in SCM at the same time, like:

[multiple repos screenshot (from my recollection)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkK93.png)

But now, I see only single repo at a time:

[single repo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGYCS.png)

Can I go back to the past?

Comment: Did this setting get changed: `Scm > Providers: Visible`? The default is `10` did yours get changed to `1` or `0`?

Comment: It's `10` in my setting.